# How to associate subplots with a particular figure number?

Tags: python, matplotlib

coming from MATLAB, I am trying to perform something like how subplots are associated with a figure number:

```
figure(3)
subplot(3,1,1)
```

How would I do this in Python? Below is where I am stuck.

```
plt.figure(3)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3)
```

Comment: You'll need to consult the matplotlib documentation or follow a beginner tutorial. Guessing what the function parameters are supposed to be isn't likely to work out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add subplots to the figure you created

```
fig = plt.figure(3)
axs = fig.add_subplot(3, 1, 1)
```

or you can create both using `subplots`, so the previous call of `figure` is not needed

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1)
```